# ScrollView no funciona "Android Studio"

Tags: android, xml, scroll

La verdad tengo un poco de conocimientos básicos en programación Android y demás. Estoy haciendo una aplicación en Android Studio que trata de hacer una pantalla principal para que un docente y padre de familia se puedan registrar e iniciar sesión. En la actividad en la que el padre de familia se registra tengo muchos `EditText` y algunos `RadioButton`, y cada uno de ellos en varios `LinearLayout`s para mantener un mejor orden. Es por eso que intenté poner un **`ScrollView`** para que se pueda ir bajando por la pantalla.

El problema es que ya lo implementé encerrando todo lo que necesito que sea Scroll y no funciona. También declaré el contenedor padre como Scroll y tampoco funciona; al instalar la APK en mi Moto G para probarlo, no funciona el `ScrollView`.

Este es el Archivo XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#3399cc"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="joinder.proyecto.Main_formulario_padre">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="136dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#ffffff">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:hint="Nombre :"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:hint="Apellido :"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText5"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:hint="Correo :"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText6"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:hint="Telefono :"
                    android:inputType="phone" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText7"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:hint="Contraseña :"
                    android:inputType="textPassword" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText12"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:hint="Repetir Contraseña :"
                    android:inputType="textPassword" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Padre"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:onClick="OnRadioButtonClicked"/>

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Madre"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:onClick="OnRadioButtonClicked"/>

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Acudiente"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:onClick="OnRadioButtonClicked"/>

            </RadioGroup>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:background="@drawable/border_radius_2"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

La etiqueta `ScrollView` ya pueden ver que automáticamente la omite la plataforma; está justo antes de empezar el primer `LinearLayout`.

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Como es que no tienes el name space xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  en el ScrollView?? Copia y pega las primeras 4 linias de mi respuesta y cambialas por tu declaración del ScrollView

Comment: No tampoco compañero, es raro, solo hace un poco de scroll al tocar uno de los EditTexts con etiqueta flotante, pero no baja mucho, nunca me muestra el Button de Registrarme que lo tengo puesto al final y que obviamente no se ve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asigna la propiedad scrollbars a tu ScrollView asi

```
 <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">
```

Ademas remueve el marginTop que le pusistes al linearLayout dentro del scrollView y añadeselo como paddingTop al Layout principal y con eso funciona.

Comment: Wow, muchisimas gracias, creeme que llevaba desde ayer buscando una solucion y nada. Te lo agradezco @Andres.

Answer (score 1):

El `ScrollView` solo puede tener un layout hijo, de manera que debes poner todo tu contenido dentro de un layout como `LinearLayout` por ejemplo y éste dentro del `ScrollView`

**Ejemplo:**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/your_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

         // ...

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Umm entiendo, debe ser eso, ya que como comente, tengo al grupo de radiobuttons en un Layout y al grupo de EditTexts en otro Layout y todo eso dentro del LinearLayout hijo del Scroll.

Comment: Muchas gracias @MarcGV cualquier cosa te comentare.

Comment: @ChechoParrado si esta es la respuesta correcta, por favor márcala como **"respuesta correcta"** para ayudar a futuros desarrolladores (es un check que esta donde se vota positiva o negativamente la respuesta)

Comment: No, no funciona, deje un solo LinearLayout con todo dentro y este mismo dentro del ScrollView y sigue el problema, al ejecutarlo en el telefono solo baja un poco al tocar una de las etiquetas flotantes, cabe recordar que cada EditText tiene el efecto de etiqueta flotante, no se si eso sea la causa, pero lo he quitado tambien y sigue lo mismo, no se si  estoy haciendo algo mal.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon el código de tu layout completo con el ScrollView añadido

Comment: Listo, elimine los TextInputLayout a ver si eso causaba algun problema pero no, sigue igual.

Answer (score 1):

Esto sucede cuando agregamos medidas fijas dentro del `ScrollView` en este caso el margen:

```
android:layout_marginTop="136dp"
```

en lugar de un margen puedes usar padding

```
android:paddingTop="136dp"
```

o agregar una vista al layout.

---

El `LinearLayout` que contiene el ScrollView no es necesario, puedes omitirlo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el Tip, lo tendré en cuenta de ahora en adelante.

Comment: Cuando den -1 al menos podrían indicar cual es el problema?